# Проблема с распараллеливанием цикла в OpenMP

Tags: openmp, распараллеливание, c++

Допустим, есть вектор odds, который хранит количество чётных и нечётных чисел, и есть вектор numbers, который хранит сами эти числа.

Цикл, распараллеливаемый OpenMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
{
    ++(odds[numbers[i] % 2]);
}
```

Последовательная и параллельная версии этого цикла дают разный результат. Где баг?

Comment: Жуть какая-то с форматированием.. Мой первый вопрос))

Answer (score 2):

С атомарным доступом конечно, можно, но смысл? Он жутко замедлит работу и эффект распараллеливания просто не будет заметен.

Я бы написал так

```
int uneven = 0, even = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:uneven) reduction (+:even)
for (i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    (a[i]%2) ? (uneven++) : (even++);    
}    
odd[0] = even;
odd[1] = uneven;
```

Код, может, несколько корявый , но, мне кажется, намного эффективнее будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, кажется, понял!
Надо поставить #pragma omp atomic перед операцией в цикле для корректного доступа к разделяемому ресурсу=)